# Adding configurable preconditions to variadic Function<Args...> class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I wrote a class to execute functions with arbitrary arguments. This works as intended, but as an additional feature, I would like to add preconditions that derived classes can configure in their constructors.

Preconditions could be something like std::function<bool(ArgType_i)> that return true if the argument is ok. Bonus points if combinations of parameters can be checked.

Maybe I just need a single std::vectorstd::function<bool(FunctionArguments...), where each precondition selects the argument(s) it needs to checks... but how would I make that work with reusable precondition elements, such as std::bind(std::greater, std::placeholders::_1, 0) that is supposed to check if only one of the arguments is greater than zero?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
template <typename FunctionArguments...>
class OperationWithArgumentsTemplate
{
public:
  bool Execute(FunctionArguments args...)
  {
    // Execute() works, but I would like to add configurable preconditions like so
    // if(!CheckPreconditions(args...)){return false;}

    return m_fct(args...);
  }

protected:
  // What could this signature look like?
  void RegisterPrecondition();

private:
  std::function<bool(FunctionArguments...)> m_fct;

  bool CheckPreconditions(FunctionArguments args...)
  {
    // for each tuple entry in m_preconditions: check all preconditions on argument i
  }

  // ??? std::tuple<std::vector<Precondition<T1>>, std::vector<Precondition<T2>>, ...> m_preconditionsOnIndividualArgs;
  // ??? std::vector<std::function<bool(FunctionArguments...)>> m_vecPreconditionsOnAllArgs;
};

class MyConcreteOperation : public OperationWithArgumentsTemplate<double, double>
{
  MyConcreteOperation()
  {
    // RegisterPreconditions<???>(/* e.g. first double must be positive, second must be larger than 5 */);
  }
};
```

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/MMd7z8fT7), perhaps.